# What kind of encoding is this gibberish

Tags: pdf, text, encoding

This file I downloaded is supposed to be a PDF (I think, could be just a text file for all I know) but see the picture below for what the file looks like. Does anyone know what this is or if it can be converted?

[image]

Comment: What are we looking at here exactly?  Is this an image of the string that results when the file is parsed as 8-bit ASCII?

Comment: PDFs usually contain streams of compressed data, and they might look like your excerpt  (but the same is true for e.g. ZIP files and all the formats using them as container). To say anything concrete, share the whole file or at least a start segment and an end segment as there usually are some relevant hints.

Answer (score 1):

If it's from a PDF file, it is likely to be Flate encoded (the same type of compression as is used with zip files, but no you cannot open a PDF file with a zip utility). This is the most common compression in a PDF for non-image data.  It's not ASCIIHex or ASCII85 encoded. It could be but likely isn't LZW or RunLength (RLE) encoded.  If it is image data, it could be CITTFax, JBIG2, DCT (essentially JPEG), or JPX (JPEG 2000) encoded.

In some cases, it is possible that parts of a PDF might be encoded by more than one of these filters, so a combination of say, DCT and ASCII85, could be used. but this isn't as common anymore.

Or the PDF file could be encrypted, in which case you have a choice of RC4 or different flavors of AES encryption. It's also possible that custom encryption was used (e.g. if the PDF file is an E-Book).

The screenshot you provided doesn't contain enough information to determine what the case may be for that particular part of the file, but the end conclusion you basically need to read your PDF file with software that understands the PDF format; a text editor won't do.